# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when accessing user profile information

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I have created a different identity table **MyUserInfo** for my user profile where I store additional info such as Name, address etc. The idea is that if the user has not entered his / her data then he will be sent to another page where it can be done. The issue is that when I try to verify if the client has entered his name, address etc... i get an an error and I don't understand why:

**Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

this happens at the line where I try to check if the value of the User Name is null

```
if (currentUser.MyUserInfo.FirstName == null)
```

Here is the code:

```
string user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
store.AutoSaveChanges = false;

var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

//check if the user is registered and what his role is
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated &&  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Customer"))
{
    if (currentUser.MyUserInfo.FirstName == null) //offending line
    {
        Response.Redirect("EnterUserData.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try placing a breakpoint on the line where the error happens and checking the value of `currentUser` and `MyUserInfo` to make sure they're not null?  Are you sure that if a non-null object is returned by `manager.FindById` that the MyUserInfo property will not be null?

Comment: Well Either currentUser or currentUser.MyUserInfo is null, put a debug on it, find out which one and then suss out why.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Hi Thank you ... currentUser is set but MyUserInfo is null

Comment: Um just test for that as well then. if ((currentUser.MyUserInfo == null) || (currentUser.MyUserInfo.FirstName == null))

Comment: I made it work, just like I said below MyUserInfo had to instantiated as well, I solved it by currentUser.MyUserInfo = new MyUserInfo(); then accessing the information  currentUser.MyUserInfo.FirstName = FirstName.Text; and finally store.Context.SaveChanges(); just like in any other entity class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `manager.FindByID()` returns null, you will get that exception when you try and reference properties in the `currentUser` object (which of course would also be null).  In addition, `currentUser.MyUserInfo` could be null, causing the same issue.

Comment: thank you for the help, I have been testing and verified that the currentUser object is not null,  it is set. MyUserInfo is an (identity) entity class that makes a table where I store profile information about the user, and the corresponding table has been created. I still don’t understand how this is possible, I am just trying to set the user info that goes in the MyUserInfo table. How to make MyUserInfo not null?

Comment: It was confusing but ... the thing that made it work was  currentUser.MyUserInfo = new MyUserInfo();